# If A and B are both diagonalizable to another matrix C, is A similar to B?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, similar-matrices

Since A and B are diagonalizable to C so

PAP^-1 =C and so as B(QBQ-1= C)

Which is PAP^-1 = QBQ-1= C

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, similarity is transitive. Indeed it is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

$$PAP^{-1}=QBQ^{-1} \implies A=P^{-1}QBQ^{-1}P$$

$$ A= (P^{-1}Q)B(P^{-1}Q)^{-1}$$